# Psexec through Python: Could not install PSEXEC service issue

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, psexec

When I run a psexec command from my command prompt it perfectly opens the application on the remote desktop. But when I try to do the same thing through the Python script below it gives "Could not install PSEXEC service. Access is denied"

```
#!/usr/bin/env/python

import os
import subprocess

##Path of psexec in my laptop
psexecpath = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\PSTools\\PsExec.exe"

##Command structure to run Psexec on the remote machine
command = ' '+ '-s' + ' ' + '-i' + ' ' + '1' + ' ' + '-u' + ' ' + 'administrator' + ' ' + '-p' + ' ' + 'force' + ' ' + '\\135.20.230.160' + ' '

##Path of the application in the remote system
xtocdpath = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tensilica\\Xtensa OCD Daemon 9.0.3\\xt-ocd.exe"

final_command = psexecpath + command + xtocdpath

subprocess.Popen(final_command, shell = False)
```

---

Any clue where I might be going wrong ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running your script in Windows or Linux. ?
This usually happens when the user doesn't have permission to open ports.

If windows, try running your script in Administrator Command Prompt.
If linux, try running your script as root user.

Comment: Yes, I can see different outputs when run through Administrator Command Prompt. But I am still stuck, this might be due to syntax. The error now is:

Comment: PsExec could not start \135.20.230.160 on MININT-6NUJKB6:
The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: In the error it is showing a single blackslash instead of two for the IP address. I doubt whether I am giving the IP address of the remote computer correctly

Comment: can u paste your actual command here which you are running in your command prompt.. I will check.